# electrode-ignite - generating app - TypeError: Cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined

Tags: node.js, walmart-electrode

Here's the versions of relevant global packages

```
xclap-cli@0.1.3
electrode-ignite@3.0.14
npm@6.10.1
node@12.6.0
nvm@0.34.0
```

Here's the error I'm getting after trying to generate an *Electrode Application* using `electrode-ignite` CLI tool.

```sh
/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/global-tunnel-ng/lib/agents.js:17
  mixinProxying(this, opts.proxy);
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined
    at new OuterHttpAgent (/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/global-tunnel-ng/lib/agents.js:17:28)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:116:13)
    at TunnelingAgent.request (http.js:44:10)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/tunnel/lib/tunnel.js:126:25)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/tunnel/lib/tunnel.js:207:41)
    at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/tunnel/lib/tunnel.js:84:8)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:276:16)
    at Object.request (https.js:309:10)
    at Object.request (/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/global-tunnel-ng/index.js:336:40)
    at get (/Users/vn00ach/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/electrode-ignite/node_modules/github-username/node_modules/got/index.js:49:18)
[08:45:58] Generator: electrode failed with exit code 1. This could mean that it didn't generate your app properly. Please double check.
```

Here're are the options I placed into the CLI prompt (defaults):

```
? Application Name test-electrode
? Description
? Project homepage url
? Which framework for the server? HapiJS
? Author's Name <omitted>
? Author's Email <omitted>
? Author's Homepage
? Package keywords (comma to split)
? Would you like to make a Progressive Web App? No
? Use double quotes or single quotes? "
? Would you like to create a new directory for your project? Yes
? Would you like to generate .flowconfig for flow usage? No
? Would you like to enable critical CSS? Yes
? Would you like to enable support for CSS Module (requires postcss)? Yes
? Would you like to enable postcss for processing CSS? Yes
? Would you like to use jest for unit tests? Yes
? Would you like to use mocha? Yes
? Would you like to use typescript? Yes
? Would you like to use sinon? Yes
? Would you like to use eslint? Yes
```